# Count index combinations in two lists of same length

Tags: python, list

I have two lists: `list_a` and `list_b` of the same length. However, the length is variable, the following example is just a simplification.

The values in the arrays are variable, too, but I know which values could possibly occur. The optional values are listed in `options_a` and `options_b`.

```
list_a = ['metro', 'metro', 'urban', 'urban', 'rural']
list_b = [1, 2, 2, 2, 3]

options_a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
options_b = ['metro', 'urban', 'suburb', 'rural']
```

I want to count the occurrences of `option_b`-options for each option in `options_a` and print that in a matrix:

```
[
 [1, 0, 0, 0],       #tells me that options_a=1 has the option_b='metro' exactly once
 [1, 2, 0, 0],       #options_a=2 has the option_b='metro'once, option_b='urban' twice
 [0, 0, 0, 1],       #options_a=3 has the option_b='rural' exactly once
 [0, 0, 0, 0]        #options_a=4 did not occur
]
```

However, my approach does not work, and I don't know how to correct it:

```
output = list(map(lambda x: 

                list(map(lambda y: list_a.count(y), options_b))

    , options_a))

print(output)
```

Results in output:

```
>>>[
    [2, 2, 0, 1],
    [2, 2, 0, 1],
    [2, 2, 0, 1],
    [2, 2, 0, 1]
   ]
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are currently just counting each word from `options_b` in `list_a` again and again. What you are missing is to count it only if the number in `list_b` matches with the number from `options_a`. To do that you can use the [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) function to pack word-number together and then count the pairs:

```py
pairs = list(zip(list_a, list_b))
output = [[pairs.count((word, num)) for word in options_b] for num in options_a]

print(output)
# [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

I have changed to a list-comp because I believe it is more readable than the use of `list(map(lambda ...))`...

---

To avoid looping again and again (`count` will actually loop the list each time), you can use a [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter):

```py
from collections import Counter

pair_counts = Counter(zip(list_a, list_b))
output = [[pair_counts[(word, num)] for word in options_b] for num in options_a]

print(output)
# [[1, 0, 0, 0], [1, 2, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 0, 0, 0]]
```